# Excel Sheet - how to add condition in VLookUp

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with two sheets, sheet1 and sheet2. 
The sheet2 data is:

```
Name    Teacher
A       A
B       Ba
C       C
D       D
```

The sheet1 has following data

```
Sno Name    Teacher Class

1   A       A       5
2   B       Ba      5
3   C       C       6
4   D       D       5
```

Here the teacher column has got a formula `=VLOOKUP(B2, sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)` on every cell. In this formula B2 will change as per the row , like b3, b4,etc.

I want to change this formula such that if Name is not found in sheet2 then add the same name in the Teacher column. Like I have "E" Name and it is not found in Sheet2 then "E" should appear in the Teacher column and not "#N/A". 
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),B2)
```

(Applicable to XL2007+)

Comment: -1 `IFERROR` hides errors other than a missed match

Answer (score 2):

[image]I think you want your formula to be

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B6, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)),B6,VLOOKUP(B6, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE))`

This will check specifically for NA, any other error will still throw an error and not substitute E for teacher.

Comment: Both the above answers work well for me. Thank you guys!